# Setting cookie in Internet Explorer 3.0?

Tags: html, http, cookies, internet-explorer-3

I'm having issues setting session cookies in Internet Explorer 3.0. Does anyone know if there is something special that needs to be done?

I'm doing with PHP, like so: `setcookie('test', '1');`

I'm not using a path or expiration time, is that necessary?

Perhaps someone has some old experience, or a 1997-1998 web development book laying around?

In case anyone is wondering why I'm bothering with this, because no-one uses IE3 anymore, and it's hard, yadda yadda, it's an art project.

Edit: Just to clarify, I have not tried setting cookies via JS yet, this is being done via HTTP.

Comment: IE 3? WHAT? document.all FTW! Honestly all that knowledge I had from 1998 on my old IBM with notepad is no longer in my brain. lol

Comment: The status on caniuse.com is unknowm, [see here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_document_cookie). Maybe you could use something else than cookie, or, you know, **not** IE3.

Comment: Might be useful to give some more detail on the issues you're having, as [MDN says IE supports set cookie headers.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've gotten to the bottom of this issue, and there were three causes for my confusion:

First, if you don't set a path= parameter for the cookie, IE3 will assume that the cookie is for *this exact path only*. This means that it will send back the same cookie when accessing `/test.php` again, but nowhere else on the site.

The solution is to include path=/ when setting the cookie.

Second, IE3 does not recognize cookies without an Expires parameter. The solution is to include Expires= in the Set-Cookie header, in "standard" cookie format.

The third is caused by the new Max-Age parameter, helpfully added by PHP for some reason, which IE3 does not recognize. Instead, it assumes everything up to and including Max-Age is the cookie name.

The solution is to set the cookie using PHP's `header()` function instead, like so:

`header('Set-Cookie: test2=hi; expires=Tue, 02-Feb-2021 04:20:00 GMT; path=/');`

(In this case, test2 is the name of the cookie, hi is the contents, and it expires about a year from today, on Feb 2nd.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the `setCookie` was around at this time. You could, however, use the older way of setting cookie which is

```
document.cookie = "someCookie=someCookievalue"
```

or

```
document.cookie += "someCookie=someCookievalue"
```

if you don't want to override cookie.

You can then retreive it using the `document.cookie` property. This will return a string of all the cookie. you can parse them using this function.

```js
function parseCookie(cookiesString) {
  var cookiesOutput = {};
  var cookieKeysAndValue = cookiesString.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < cookieKeysAndValue.length; i++){
   var keyAndValue = cookieKeysAndValue[i].split('=');
   cookiesOutput[keyAndValue[0]] = keyAndValue[1];
  }
  return cookiesOutput
}

document.cookie = 'someCookie=SomeCookieValue';
console.log(parseCookie(document.cookie));
```

I'm not 100% sure this will work since, you know, you are using Internet Explorer 3. But it is worth a shot.

If you need more information on that, you can [consult the MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

**P.S.** I tried to write something *old javascript type* as much as I could, but there still might have some errors. I already miss the modern browser feature.

Comment: FYI, and I know you mentioned that this may not work in your post (I just thought you may be interested); [`string.split` is only supported from IE4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: [And `console.log` only from IE8!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Comment: @OliverRadini oh no ! Well i'm out of idea. What did people use to split string before `String.split()` ?

Comment: I have no idea ha, must have just used a loop and kept track of things manually? Probably not actually that hard to do, but tedious to repeat!

Comment: setcookie() is a PHP function which I'm using to send the cookie from the server-side over HTTP...